# Define a function that strings 2 s-expressions together

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

If I run

```
(defn c [a b]
  (-> a
      b))

(c (+ 1 2 3)
   (partial * 4))
```

it returns the result of `(* 4 (+ 1 2 3))` which is `24`

Suppose I want to invoke `c` without using a partial for the second s-expression i.e.

```
(c (+ 1 2 3)
   (* 4))
```

and get the same result `24`.

What would the `(defn c...)` look like?

Comment: It needs to look like a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a [macro](http://www.braveclojure.com/read-and-eval/), which is a function that takes code and returns code. For instance, you want this code

```
(c (+ 1 2 3)
   (* 4))
```

to be equivalent to this code:

```
(-> (+ 1 2 3)
    (* 4))
```

You can write your `c` macro using Clojure's [syntax quote](http://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/#Syntax_Quoting) like this:

```
(defmacro c [a b]
  `(-> ~a ~b))
```

You can then test your macro using the [`macroexpand-1`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand-1) function:

```
(macroexpand-1
 '(c (+ 1 2 3)
     (* 4)))
;;=> (clojure.core/-> (+ 1 2 3) (* 4))
```

Success!

```
(c (+ 1 2 3)
   (* 4))
;;=> 24
```

Comment: Great thanks Sam. I was wondering when I'd finally have to start writing macros...

Comment: @monch1962 Well, in this particular case, you still don't need to write any macros, because here `c` just provides a subset of the functionality of `->`.

Comment: it's unlikely that you actually *need* to use a macro here. Or at least you should make some effort to find another way first.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Agreed. Macros are great when you need them, but that's rarer than you'd think; whenever possible, you should avoid writing macros.

Comment: please, never make a macro the *only* way to call your function, the longer i write clojure the fewer macros I write per year (ps: it's zero for 2016)

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt The question I asked is a fairly massive reduction of a much larger problem I'm having - in real life, my 'c' function needs to loop through successively larger subsets of the result returned by 'a', applying 'b' to each of those subsets and accumulating the result across all the subsets of 'a'. Writing the macro as Sam described makes the code a lot more readable

Answer (score 1):

the arguments to clojure functions are evaluated to values before the function call is made. Functions are a great value to choose if you want to pass in a value that does something inside the function you are passing it to. **always prefer values to functions, and functions to macros**. because a value isn't useful here `(* 4)` evaluates to just `4`.

your first example is taking one value and one function and calling that function with that value. To make this more clear I could rewrite that example with different variable names:

```
(defn c' [initial-value function-to-call]
    (-> initial-value
        function-to-call)
```

and if I remove the thread first macro it becomes more clear:

```
(defn c'' [initial-value function-to-call]
   (function-to-call initial-value))
```

so we can see that the second argument needs to be a function before it can be called with a value. If it is passed as an s-expression that has not already been compiles into a function then it will need to be made into a function before it can be run with a value.

You can accomplish this in several ways, ordered here from best (what you should almost certainly do in just about every case) to to vastly worse (which I have never seen cause to actually do in seven years writing Clojure for a living):

1. just use the existing `->` macro (you likely have a reason not to do this because you are asking)
2. pass it a function, such as `#(* % 4)` or use partial as you already are
3. make it a macro
4. use eval to run the expression inside your function (this is unlikely)

I really advocate for option one, it does everything you are asking for and everyone who reads your code will already know what it does.

option two is a close second because everyone who reads it will quickly figure out what it does.

option three is a very distant third because it means you cannot use it with functions like map, reduce etc. and everyone will have to spend time figuring out what it does.